# Opencv Histogram Data from Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, lbph-algorithm

So I'm trying to get the actual data from the histogram I generated in OpencCV.  I'm using the code located [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/lbph_faces.cpp) and can be seen below.  However, I don't exactly know how to get the data from this `Mat`.  I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388581/3709119), but the post uses `hist.get(i, 0)` to get the histogram data.  However, my histogram `Mat` only contains 1 row... and 16384 cols.  The pertinent code is below.

```
static Mat spatial_histogram(InputArray _src, int numPatterns,
                         int grid_x, int grid_y, bool /*normed*/)
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    // calculate LBP patch size
    int width = src.cols/grid_x;
    int height = src.rows/grid_y;
    // allocate memory for the spatial histogram
    Mat result = Mat::zeros(grid_x * grid_y, numPatterns, CV_32FC1);
    // return matrix with zeros if no data was given
    if(src.empty())
        return result.reshape(1,1);
    // initial result_row
    int resultRowIdx = 0;
    // iterate through grid
    for(int i = 0; i < grid_y; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid_x; j++) {
            Mat src_cell = Mat(src, Range(i*height,(i+1)*height), Range(j*width,(j+1)*width));
            Mat cell_hist = histc(src_cell, 0, (numPatterns-1), true);
            // copy to the result matrix
            Mat result_row = result.row(resultRowIdx);
            cell_hist.reshape(1,1).convertTo(result_row, CV_32FC1);
            // increase row count in result matrix
            resultRowIdx++;
        }
    }
    // return result as reshaped feature vector
    return result.reshape(1,1);
}
```

`result` becomes a `Mat` of size 1 x 16384 and the values are sparse in the `Mat`... So how would I get the proper histogram data?

Comment: You have the result mat which is exactly what you're looking for. What do you need exactly? You can access each value like: `float val = histogram.at<float>(i);`

Comment: this is very interesting, as I'm having the same issue. can you please provide your working code?